# Dynamic router.push routs in child component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I used $router.push to create a new path and open component based on id and path of object based in .json file

```
route(item) {
    let path = this.makeRoute(item);
    this.$router.push({
      path: `/${path}/${item.id}`,
      name: 'Element',
      component: Element,
      props: true
    })
  },
  makeRoute(item) {
    const res = String(item.type) + "-" + String(item.location);
    return res;
  }
```

router-view is in the parent of a parent component and when I click on the div it says in the console that the router with name 'Element' does not exist. It's like it wants me to add a route in router.js file but if I do that then my paths won't be dynamic.

Comment: if you define the route.path in router.js as path: ":path/:id/", then you will still be able to do this.$router.push(\`/${path}/${item.id}\`)

Comment: when I do that it says in console: [vue-router] missing param for named route "Element": Expected "path" to be defined